# elm how to update model based on input type number

Tags: input, numbers, int, elm

I have an input like this :

`input [ type' "number", onInput NewValue ] [ text <| toString model.value ]`

How to update the model ? I have something like this:

```
NewValue nb ->
      ( { model | value = nb }, Cmd.none )
```

I don't know if in input type number the value is an `Int` or a `String`.
I also try this:

```
NewValue nb ->
  let
    nb = Result.withDefault 0 (String.toInt nb)
  in
    ( { model | value = nb }, Cmd.none )
```

WIth the second version I got this error:

```
The return type of function `withDefault` is being used in unexpected ways.

44|         nb = Result.withDefault 0 (String.toInt nb)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The function results in this type of value:

    Int

Which is fine, but the surrounding context wants it to be:

    String
```

Comment: Your 2nd attempt looks fine to me. What's not working?

Comment: I've added the error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the function name nb to something else as it is already assigned as a String and you can't overwrite it.

```
NewValue nb ->
  let
    newInt = Result.withDefault 0 (String.toInt nb)
  in
    ( { model | value = newInt }, Cmd.none )
```